# Why am I getting a CORS error when using the PATCH method in NestJS with TypeScript and Cors enabled?

Tags: typescript, cors, nestjs

PATCH method is blocked by cors in NestJs

The problem is the following: Method PATCH is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.

That is how I connected cors to my app.

```
  app.enableCors({
    origin: true,
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'PATCH'],
    credentials: true,
  });
```